# Two versions of the same book without differences?

Tags: amazon

On Amazon, the book [Worlds of honor 6](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Worlds-Honor-Beginnings-David-Weber/dp/1451639031/) (which hasn't been released yet), has two "formats" listed, they're both hardback but have different prices, how can I tell what the difference is?

Comment: The more expensive "format" has a marginally earlier publish date (14 July, as opposed to 16 July) - maybe these are the first prints?!

Comment: @w3d - You should add this as an answer, looking at other books I think you're right, the row with a + is the most recent edition with previous editions as sub-items, though how you can have older editions for an unreleased book I have no idea!

Comment: @w3d - Items from other sellers (Amazon marketplace) rather than direct from Amazon also introduce a new sub-item (often for the same edition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it would seem that the only difference is the date of publication. In this instance, the more expensive "format" has a marginally earlier publish date (14 July, as opposed to 16 July) so maybe these are the first prints hot off the press? Consequently you should probably expect to get it a little bit sooner and have the satisfaction that it is one of the first editions. Some of these early editions may even be numbered?